# How to make J2Me chat service as cheap as Whatsapp

Tags: java-me, chat

I am trying to make a I.M client using J2ME so that I can chat with my friends.
The aim is to learn something new. What I need to understand is that --- how do I make it cheap like Whatsapp?

According to Wiki, whatsapp uses XMPP. Is it the reason why its extremely cheap to send receive messages in Whatsapp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason whatsapp is relatively cheap is that mobile phone providers have been overcharging us for the data in text messages. Whatsapp uses your mobile phone's data plan to send and recieve data (which is usually flat rate/fair use) thus bypassing the mobile phone operator costs of sending text messages. Text messaging itself not data intensive by nature so I don't see why one protocol would be particularly cheaper than another.

Also take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jabbermixclient/ it's a j2me application that connects to a jabber server using the XMPP protocol, maybe you can learn something from that.

GL&HF!